# Find $10^{5^{101}}$ modulo $21$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Most of the solutions to this question goes on by stating
$10^{5^{101}}$ as $10^{505}$. But shouldn't this be thought as $5^{101}$, not $(10)^{5\cdot 101}$?
Well if I do solve it as $10^{505}$, I get the answer as {10}.

Comment: It means that most of the solutions to this question that you had seen were simply wrong, as is a lot of "popular mathematics".

Comment: $10^{5^{101}}\neq 10^{505}$... unless you mean $(10^{5})^{101}$.  Written without parenthesis one must remember the order of operations... $5^{101}\neq 505$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it would be no fun if it were $10^{505}$.

By Little Fermat, $10^6\equiv 1\mod 7$  and $10^2\equiv 1\mod 3$, hence the *Chinese remainder theorem*  ensures $10^6\equiv 1\mod 21$. Thus
$$10^n\equiv10^{n\bmod 6}\pmod{21}$$

Now $5$ is invertible modulo $6$, and has order $2$ in the group $(\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z)^\times$, which means $5^{101}\equiv 5^{101\bmod2}=5\pmod6$. So, modulo $21$:
$$10^{5^{101}}\equiv 10^5=(10^2)^2\cdot10\equiv(-5)^2\cdot10\equiv 40\equiv 19.$$

In case it would have to be interpreted as $10^{505}$, it is simpler:
$$10^{505}\equiv10^{505\bmod6}=10^1=10.$$

Comment: I don't get the part where you wrote 5 is invertible modulo 6 and has order 2 in the group (Z/6Z)^x. I get that since you wrote there's order 2 in the group, 101=1(mod2) but why not 101=2 (mod 3) that 5^2=1 (mod 6)? or some else modulo?

Comment: For the  1st part of your comment: $5$ is invertible modulo $6$, because they're coprime, and indeed $5^2=25\equiv 1\mod6$, so $5$ is its own inverse. I'm sorry, I don't grasp what you mean in the 2ndpart. Why should we use $101$ modulo $3$ since $5$ has order $2$?

Comment: Now I figured out the whole procedure! Thanks!

Comment: @Bernard 

Do you mean $$(-5)^2\cdot10\equiv 40\equiv 19.$$

Comment: @Stack: Yes. I supposed it was late when I answered, and messed up between $5^2=25$  and the modulus… Thanks for pointing it!